# scss.erb ruby code not executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass

I am trying to load a background image which is stored on Rackspace's CloudFiles in my Stylesheet file. I used Fog & CarrierWave to upload the image file and to call the file. I keep on getting this error:

> Invalid CSS after "...und-image: url(": expected ")", was "<%= design.main..."

preview.css.scss.erb:

```
html{
     background-image: url(<%= design.main_image_url.to_s %>);
}
```

---

Update: I rephrase my question and I got an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752142/passing-instance-variable-to-stylesheet-assets)

What I should have ask was "How to pass an instance variable to assets?" - Which you can can't

Comment: Hello Moose, I see you end up solving this by using ERB along with the HTML itself. I'm having exactly the same issue right now, but I can't do it with HTML. Have you managed a way around using ERB inside of SASS?

Answer (score 0):

Put the url in quotes.

```
url('<%= design.main_image_url.to_s %>');
```

Comment: That didn't work, the page loaded without the background image.  Instead <%= design.main_image_url.to_s %> was visible in the Style when I inspect the DOM.

Comment: Hmm.  Are you sure the name of the file ends in .erb?

Comment: Yup it ends with .erb. Now its throwing me a `undefined local variable or method `design'` error. I change it to `@design.main_image_url.to_s` and updated my controller, but still its giving me the same error

Comment: I hate to keep giving you minor iterations that may not work, but would you mind trying either a class method or a constant, Design::MAIN_IMAGE_URL or Design.main_image_url?  I'm not sure that the assets have access to controller variables.

Comment: Hey Caleb, I think this is more then a variable issue. I just faced this same problem with a much simpler code. If you dont' mind, [have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293878/sass-with-erb-wont-compile).