# Passing instance variable to stylesheet assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How do I pass an instance variable from my controller to my assets stylesheet?

Can I do something like this

preview_controller.rb

```
def show
 @design = Design.first
end
```

and my assets file is

preview.css.scss.erb

```
body{
  background-image: url('<%= @design.image_url.to_s %>');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this (the assets are pre-compiled and do no have access to variables from the request). You could have this in your HTML page itself:

```
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
  <style>
  body{
    background-image: url('<%= @design.image_url.to_s %>');
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
..
```

It would achieve the same end result.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. Totally forgot about embedding the stylesheet in HTML.