# Variable in css file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4

This is a part of my css file:

```
.parallax-image-2 {
    background: url('/assets/tuscany.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;/* IE FIX */
}
```

How can i use variable in the css file? Is that possibly? Like this

```
.parallax-image-2 {
    background: url('/assets/#{@region.name}');
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;/* IE FIX */
}
```

thanks...remco

Comment: unless that css file gets 'executed' or parsed by ruby, you can't just start throwing other languages in there and hope to have it "just work".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing instance variable to stylesheet assets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752142/passing-instance-variable-to-stylesheet-assets)

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3.1+ asset pipelines makes us able to use asset helpers in css files. Now ruby parser is able to resolve some of the issues e.g. image path. You just need to add `.css.erb` as instead of `.css` as stylesheet file extension.

```
.my_class {
  background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'my_image.png' %>);
}

.my_class1 {
  background: url(<%= asset_data_uri 'logo.png' %>)
}
```

Read **[more](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets)** about asset pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

**Assets**

Bottom line is that unless you're rendering your assets ad-hoc (not static), then the most extensible & reliable way to achieve this is to create different classes (ids) for each region

I downvoted `@Raj`'s answer because that relies on using `ERB` code in your CSS. Whilst this will be fine *if* the file is loaded ad-hoc, it will **not** work if you precompile your assets (hence loading them statically)

--

**SCSS**

I'd personally use the [**SCSS** Rails preprocessor](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
.parallax-image {
   $regions: tuscany lombardy campania;
   @each $region in $regions {
        $i: index($regions, $region);
       &.#{$i} { 
           background: asset_url('#{$region}.jpg');
       }
   }
}
```

This will allow you to call:

```
<% @regions = %w(tuscany lombardy campania)
<% @regions.each do |region| %>
   <a href="#your_link" class="parallax-image #{region}">
<% end %>
```

--

This is the best way to achieve what you want, as it will work even with [asset precompilation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)

You must remember that CSS is front-end, which means it will not lend itself to Ruby / Rails code at all. After all, it's just a styling system

Comment: hey Rich..sorry bro to comment here.. Can u please help me in this  http://goo.gl/10ghho